# How to find sine^-1 (sine inverse) in lua

Tags: lua, trigonometry, inverse

I just need a function that gives me the inverted sine.
I've tried using

```
math.sin(x)^-1
```

but that doesn't work...
How do you find the inverted sine of a number in lua?

Comment: You want to get the angle given the sin of the number? or you actually want 1/sin(x) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you mean arcsin ?

```
math.asin(x)
```

Answer (score 1):

I odn't know about Lua, but in most languages there's a function named asin() or arcsin().